# PowerShell add full path to filename and copy

Tags: file, powershell, copy

How can I copy the folder names to the filenames during the copy. At the moment the script copies only files from the subdirectory without all folder and sub-foldername. However, I want which takes the absolute pathname while copying.

**Here an example:**
Folder1
  Subfolder1
    Subfolder2
      Subfolder3
        Subfolder4
         File1
Folder2

Then a copied file would be called so:

**Folder1_Subfolder1_Subfolder2_Subfolder3_Subfolder4_File.pdf**

```
     Powershell code:
     Get-ChildItem –path C:\12  -Recurse -Include "*.???"  |
     Foreach-Object  { copy-item -Path $_.fullname -Destination c:\12 }
```

Comment: If you do that, aren't you just copying them right back to the same location?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Ok, if I'm understanding you correctly, you want a file like:

```
C:\12\foo\bar\baz.txt
```

To be copied to:

```
C:\12\foo_bar_baz.txt
```

If I'm understanding that correctly, then something like the following should work:

```
function Copy-FileUsePath {
[cmdletbinding()]
    param(
        [parameter(Mandatory=$true,Position=0)][string]$Path,
        [parameter(Mandatory=$true,Position=1)][string]$Destination
    )

    $files = Get-ChildItem -Path $Path -Recurse -Include "*.???"
    foreach ( $file in $files ) {
        $discard = $Destination.Length
        if( $Destination -notlike "*\" ) {
            $discard++
        }
        $newFileName = $file.FullName.Replace('\', '_').Remove( 0, $discard )
        $newFile = $Destination + '\' + $newFileName
        Write-Verbose "Copy-Item -Path $file.fullname -Destination $newFile"
        Copy-Item -Path $file.fullname -Destination $newFile
    }
}
```

To use this, save it to a file (I called it Copy-FileUsePath.ps1), and you can do the following:

```
. .\Copy-FileUsePath.ps1
Copy-FileUsePath -Path C:\12 -Destination C:\export
```

Comment: @HunterEdison: I suppose you want to replace `.Substring(3)` by either `.Replace($Destination, "")` or `.Remove (0, $Destination.length)` to be portable

Comment: Hi thx for your help yes you are right. But can you change your function so, that i can put path and destination as variable in to the source code. You can use c:\12 as path and c:\export as destination Sorry i have not much experiance with powershell.

Comment: I get and error if i call the funcgtion:                                              Copy-FileUsePath("D:\test\Folder1", "D:\test")                                    error msg=Copy-FileUsePath : Die Argumenttransformation für den Parameter "Path" kann nicht verarbeitet werden. Der Wert kann nicht in den Typ "System.String" konvertiert werden.
Bei Zeile:18 Zeichen:17+ Copy-FileUsePath <<<< ("D:\test\Folder1", "D:\test") + CategoryInfo : InvalidData: (:) [Copy-FileUsePath], ParameterBindin...mationException
+ FullyQualifiedErrorId : ParameterArgumentTransformationError,Copy-FileUsePath

Comment: The parentheses are causing a problem, it's making it think everything in the parentheses as the first parameter, not splitting it into two separate parameters.

Comment: Thanks, @MatM, I think the version I have up there now is a bit more portable (had more trouble than I should have dealing w/ the trailing "\" on the destination path that may or may not be there)

Comment: @HunterEdison: drop the $discard part (including the remove) and replace `$newFile = $Destination + '\' + $newFileName` with `$newFile = Join-Path $Destination $newFileName`. It will handle "\" issue for you

Comment: @MatM: Yeah, the problem was trying to figure how much to discard from the front... but using Join-Path would have been a better choice than just concat'ing the strings together...